# document keydown bind not working for input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hotkeys

I have been using jquery hotkeys plugin from [jeresig's hotkey](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys). Shortcuts work fine when the document is in focus, but when the focus is in input fields, the shortcuts are not working. I have used `$(document)` or `$(document).find('input')` for binding. But these are not working either.

I have used this following code for making shortcut:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        shortcutsInit(); 
});

function shortcutsInit(){
    $(document).bind('keydown', "shift+f2", function() {
        window.location.replace("/list");
        return false;
    });

    $(document).bind('keydown', "f3", function() {
        if($('#searchholder').length){
           $('#searchholder').focus();
        }
        console.log('f3 pressed');
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e){
        if(e.shiftKey && (e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode) == 113){
                window.location.replace("/list");
                return false;
        }
        if((e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode) == 114){
            if($('#searchholder').length)
                $('#searchholder').focus();
            console.log('f3 pressed');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not based on my question but thanks for your answer. This is an alternate solution and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these options are solving the problem:

```
$.hotkeys.options.filterInputAcceptingElements = false;
$.hotkeys.options.filterTextInputs = false;
```

Comment: where to set this options?